# Установка Metasploit на iPhone

Tags: ios, ruby, iphone, svn

Я пытаюсь установить *Metasploit* на *iPhone*, но на этапе установки самого метасплоита выдает ошибку *Subversion*.

Я установил:

- `ruby 1.9.2` из сидии
- также `iconv 1.14-1`
- и `zlib 1.2.3-1`

но при установке самого *Metasploit* ошибка:

```
iPhone:/private/var root# svn co https://www.metasploit.com/svn/framework3/trunk/ msf3
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.0.dylib 
Referenced from: /usr/bin/svn
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.0.dylib: mmap() error 22 at 
address=0x00159000, size=0x00001000 segment=__DATA in Segment::map() 
mapping /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.0.dylib
    /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.0.dylib: mmap() error 22 at 
address=0x00181000, size=0x00001000 segment=__DATA in Segment::map() 
mapping /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.0.dylib
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: @0xdb Что именно вам не понятно в моем вопросе? С удовольствием исправлюсь если вы укажите мне на мою ошибку.

Comment: @0xdb В каком смысле? Вопрос не править? Хорошо

Comment: Ну да, теперь можете править, если есть необходимость.

Comment: @0xdb Хорошо, спасибо за помощь с форматированием.